Missing Vertex groups with imported FBX
I'm trying to import an FBX from another app but the vertex groups are missing.
The groups import fine on an OBJ but not an FBX (which I do need)
Is it possible to import vertex groups via an FBX?

Yes it is. How did you verify that the other software exported the groups in the fbx?

I use Modo and added a Part (its essentially a vertex group and the same as a Polygroup in ZBrush). An OBJ will carry them across to blender but they wont export in an FBX

Why don't you use the obj export? (I'm just trying to find a workaround for you, don't know anything about modo exports.)

I noticed that FBX export with rigged mesh is missing the vertex groups in the FBX file, (import the created fbx file in a new blender window), to get vertex groups into an FBX, i had to also include/select the armature when exporting
